# SQL*Loader and DC firewall timeout

Tags: oracle, connections, timeout, sql-loader

We are loading a huge dataset using SQLLDR and there are index creation that lasts for a couple hours or even more. Firewall drops this connection as there is no data transfer during index creation for an hour.
Oracle doesn't see this session as idle and doesn't drop connection, but firewall kills.

Do we have any workaround of this issue except changing firewall settings?

Answer (score 1):

[SKIP_INDEX_MAINTENANCE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-commands.html#GUID-1CF1975A-7569-4C58-BFF6-1D34352B6631)

> The SKIP_INDEX_MAINTENANCE SQL*Loader command-line parameter specifies
>   whether to stop index maintenance for direct path loads.

Then you can build the indexes after.